# Как подключить dll библиотеку в С# проект

Tags: c++, c#, visual-studio-2013

Здравствуйте!
уважаемое сообщество прошу вашей помощи в решении данной проблемы. Не могу подключить библиотеку dll в проект С#, получаю исключение "не удаётся найти точку входа"

Код С++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

namespace Function
{

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall ToBinary(string str)
    {

        int x1 = atoi(str.c_str());
        int b = 0, c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; x1 > 0; i++)
        {
            b = x1 % 2;
            x1 = (x1 - b) / 2;
            c += b * pow(10, i);
        }

        return c;

    }

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) string __stdcall ToHexadecimal(string str)
    {
        int ch = atoi(str.c_str());
        string s;
        if (ch == 0)
            return s = "0";

        int d;
        char m[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        while (ch != 0)
        {
            d = ch % 16;
            ch /= 16;
            s = m[d] + s;
        }

        return s;

    }
}
```

код С#

```
 [DllImport(@"Function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
        public static extern int ToBinary(string a);


    [DllImport(@"Function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
        public static extern string ToHexadecimal(string b);
```

Answer (score 5):

Вы бы хотя бы предупреждения читали:

```
warning C4190: 'ToHexadecimal' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' which is incompatible with C
```

Поэтому функция в Dll получает вовсе не то имя, которое ожидает ваше .NET приложение.

Вы неправильно передаете строки. Нужно использовать `char*` а не `std::string`.

Код на C++:

```
namespace Function
{

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall ToBinary(const char* str)
{

    int x1 = atoi(str);
    int b = 0, c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; x1 > 0; i++) {
        b = x1 % 2;
        x1 = (x1 - b) / 2;
        c += b * pow(10, i);
    }

    return c;

}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall ToHexadecimal(const char* str, char* out, int maxLength)
{
    int ch = atoi(str);
    string s;
    if (ch == 0) {
     s = "0";
    } else {

        int d;
        char m[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
        while (ch != 0) {
            d = ch % 16;
            ch /= 16;
            s = m[d] + s;
        }
    }

    strcpy_s(out, maxLength, s.c_str() );
}
}
```

Код C#

```
class Program {
        [DllImport(@"Function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int ToBinary(string a);


        [DllImport(@"Function.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void ToHexadecimal(string b,StringBuilder res, int maxLength);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int res = ToBinary("123");
            Console.WriteLine(res);
            StringBuilder res2 = new StringBuilder(256);
            ToHexadecimal("123", res2, 256);
            Console.WriteLine(res2);
        }
    }
```